Visualizing in python
I am building a credit risk model. I run into problem visualizing the data in a histogram
I tried this code:
# List of numerical columns for histogram visualization
numerical_columns = ['case_id', 'collater_valueofguarantee_1124L', 'collater_valueofguarantee_876L',
                     'num_group1', 'num_group2', 'pmts_month_158T', 'pmts_month_706T',
                     'pmts_year_1139T', 'pmts_year_507T']

# Plot histograms for each numerical column
for column in numerical_columns:
    plt.hist(df[column].dropna(), bins=20)  # Drop null values before plotting
    plt.xlabel(column)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.title(f'Histogram of {column}')
    plt.show()

And I end up with the following histograms like the attached. I can't read meaning this 
Any suggestions on how i can improve my histogram is very much welcome.
Cheers

looks like you have 10 identical entries. Is a histogram really a good way to visualize that? Is there even an interesting way to visualize a constant repeated 10 times?

For credit risk analysis, I would not use histograms, as they give no information about the distribution of the data. They simply give statistics. What I would chose, would be box plots or violin plots. They give information about outliers and density distribution.
Here are two examples:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'case_id': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
    'collater_valueofguarantee_1124L': np.random.normal(50000, 10000, 100),
    'collater_valueofguarantee_876L': np.random.normal(50000, 15000, 100),
    'num_group1': np.random.gamma(shape=2, scale=2, size=100),
    'num_group2': np.random.gamma(shape=2, scale=2, size=100),
    'pmts_month_158T': np.random.poisson(lam=300, size=100),
    'pmts_month_706T': np.random.poisson(lam=500, size=100),
    'pmts_year_1139T': np.random.randint(1, 12, 100),
    'pmts_year_507T': np.random.randint(1, 12, 100)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.boxplot(data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.title('Box Plot of Numerical Variables')
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.violinplot(data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.title('Violin Plot of Numerical Variables')
plt.show()


which gives

and


That was insightful. Thank you!
